# Does qgis support postgresql range types?

Tags: qgis, postgresql, postgis-2.0, date

I added a postgis layer with date range column in Qgis but that field is not listed in Qgis.

Comment: I think you have to set a primary key before you can view the layer in QGIS. This link has more info: http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/supported_data.html#some-details-about-postgresql-layers

Comment: I'm able to load the postgis table in Qgis but the date column field is not listed in table.